# Mysql stored procedure to return a status by testing whether record exist or not in database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Below is my simple stored procedure to get a status by testing whether record exist or not in database. here i am passing username and password every i am getting status as true even for wrong password. I should get status as true when both username and password are right else false. if record is exist i need pull that row please tell me where i am going wrong here.

**query call**

```
call login("abc","abc");
```

**SP**

```
DELIMITER $$;

        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`login`$$

        CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `login`(IN UserName varchar(50),IN Passowrd varchar(50))
        BEGIN
        DECLARE status VARCHAR(10);

             IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM register where UserName=UserName  and Passowrd=Passowrd)        
               THEN          
                   SET @status = 'TRUE';
                   SELECT @status as status; 
                   SELECT * FROM register where UserName=UserName  and Passowrd=Passowrd;         
                ELSE          
               SET @status = 'FALSE';
                   SELECT @status as status; 


                END IF;
        END$$

        DELIMITER ;$$
```

Comment: A function is more a appropriate for this case. If you insists on using procedure, you can define an OUT parameter then set a value to it. Google "mysql procedure out parameter"

Comment: As i am beginner i don't which is better, if status is true that time foward to get that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd agree with the other points being made about using a function for this test rather than a procedure but I think people are overlooking the real reason this procedure doesn't work. That is, it will always get the status as TRUE because the query is comparing each column value with itself and not against the parameters the procedure is called with.

Note, the parameters have exactly the same names as the columns that are being tested.

The SELECT query ignores the parameters and asks the question, "Is there a record in the table where this column is equal to itself and that column is also equal to itself?" Answer, "Yes" (as long as there is at least one record in the table).

This explains the TRUE status when the password doesn't match.

Try this test

```
mysql> create table abc (UserName varchar(12),Passowrd varchar(12));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.47 sec)

mysql> insert into abc value ('always','true');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> select exists 
(select 1 from abc where UserName = UserName AND Passowrd = Passowrd);
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| exists (select 1 from abc where UserName = UserName AND Passowrd = Passowrd) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                            1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You need to change the parameter names and the queries so that they test the parameters not each column against itself.

e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `login`(IN p_UserName varchar(50),IN p_Passowrd varchar(50))
```

and the tests to

```
SELECT 1 FROM register where UserName = p_UserName  and Passowrd = p_Passowrd)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM register where UserName = p_UserName  and Passowrd = p_Passowrd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable to check if there is data, you can simply do a count if userid/psw exists. See below.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`login`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `login`(IN UserName varchar(50),IN Passowrd varchar(50))
BEGIN

SET @recCount = (select count(*) from register where UserName=UserName  and Passowrd=Passowrd);
If @recCount > 0 THEN
    SELECT * FROM register where UserName=UserName  and Passowrd=Passowrd; 
END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: i did the same getting like 0 rows affected

Comment: getting status is my first goal then if status true then i need pull that record

Comment: I edited my answer. I missed the requirement to return a row of data.